# ¿Por qué no se ordena el array correctamente en Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

Tengo un array de objetos como éste (simplificado):

```
var datos = [
  { "nombre": "Prueba C", "valor":  1.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba A", "valor":  2.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba B", "valor":  4   }
];
```

Está ordenado por valor (C, A, B) pero yo quiero ordenar los elementos por nombre (A, B, C). Para ello uso `sort` con una función de comparación propia para el nombre así:

```
function(a, b) { 
  return a.nombre > b.nombre; 
}
```

La ordenación funciona sin problemas en Chrome, IE y Firefox en escritorio, pero cuando se ejecuta en Safari en iOS, el array no se ordena y se queda tal cual está. `sort` es una función nativa de JavaScript, ¿por qué falla en Safari?¿Y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Aquí dejo un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable que muestra el problema (También en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkupxoj2/)):

```js
var datos = [
  { "nombre": "Prueba C", "valor":  1.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba A", "valor":  2.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba B", "valor":  4   }
];

datos.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return a.nombre > b.nombre; 
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) debes usar está función para ordenar `strings`:

```js
var datos = [
      { "nombre": "Prueba C", "valor":  1.5 },
      { "nombre": "Prueba A", "valor":  2.5 },
      { "nombre": "Prueba B", "valor":  4   }
    ];

    datos.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return (a.nombre > b.nombre) ? 1 : (a.nombre < b.nombre) ? -1 : 0; 
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(datos));
```

> *¿Por qué falla solo en Safari?*:

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) no espera que le devuelvas valores `booleanos` (true/false) o `cadenas` (string), espera más bien un valor `entero` (integer), sea negativo, cero o positivo.

Después, cada navegador usa un algoritmo diferente para [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort):

- Safari: [`Selection Sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)
- Mozilla: [`Merge Sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- Chrome: [`Quicksort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Las especificaciones [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), no regula qué algoritmo deben usar cada uno de los navegadores.

**Un dato:** En el móvil (iPhone) usa Chrome el motor de Safari y tendrías el mismo resultado como en el navegador Safari, si no usas la [función de comparación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort#Descripci%C3%B3n).

Comment: Entonces parece que la idea es que la función de comparación debe devolver un valor entero en lugar de un booleano.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Exacto... He editado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Consulte el tipo de retorno de la función de clasificación de matriz aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort

```js
var datos = [
  { "nombre": "Prueba C", "valor":  1.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba A", "valor":  2.5 },
  { "nombre": "Prueba B", "valor":  4   }
];

datos.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.nombre > b.nombre) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.nombre < b.nombre) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a == b
  return 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));
```